# Decode JSON Double to CGFloat in Swift

Tags: json, swift, decode, translate

EDIT: The Code works, the issue was with the imported data set, which did not classify empty fields as number, but as string instead.

My app needs to import values from a JSON file in a similar construct as shown below

```
[
  {
    "id":          1,
    "string":      "Text String",
    "int":         6,
    "cgfloat":     1.1,
  }
]
```

Import:

```
id       = try container.decode(Int.self,        forKey: .id)
string   = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .string)
int      = try container.decode(Int.self,        forKey: .int)
```

I have no clue how I can read the value 1.1, neither Double nor Float, CGFloat, Int, nor String works here.
Do I need to change my data structure or is there a way to interpret this value properly in Swift?

this crashes the app:

```
let cgfloat = try container.decode(CGFloat.self, forKey: . cgfloat)
```

As requested the full code:

```
struct Monster: Codable, Comparable {
    
    enum MonsterStatus: String, Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
        
        var id: Self {
            return self
        }
 
        case Normal = "Normal"
        case Attack = "Attack"
        case Hit    = "Hit"
        case Defend = "Defend"
        case Dead   = "Dead"

    }
    
    enum MonsterType: String, Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
        
        var id: Self {
            return self
        }
        
        case Undead     = "Undead"
        case Human      = "Human"
        case Dinosaur   = "Dinosaur"
        case Dwarf      = "Dwarf"
        case Elf        = "Elf"
        case Wisp       = "Wisp"
        case Ghost      = "Ghost"
        case Beast      = "Beast"
        case Snake      = "Snake"
        case Giant      = "Giant"
        case Demon      = "Demon"
        case Dragon     = "Dragon"
        case Error      = "Error"
    }
    
    struct ImagesCatalog: Equatable, Codable {
        var Normal: String
        var Attack: String
        var Defend: String
        var Hit: String
        var Dead: String
    }
    
    
    static func < (lhs: Monster, rhs: Monster) -> Bool {
          return lhs.id < rhs.id
      }

      static func == (lhs: Monster, rhs: Monster) -> Bool {
          return lhs.id == rhs.id
      }
    var id:         Int
    let name:       String
    let image:      String          = ""
    var imagePrefix:String          = ""
    var strength:   Int             = 4
    var life:       Int             = 1
    var fleeChance: Int             = 0
    var isBoss:     Bool            = false
    var flying:     Bool            = false
    var mage:       Bool            = false
    var venomous:  Bool             = false
    var giant:      Bool            = false
    var carnivore:  Bool            = false
    var herbivore:  Bool            = false
    var type:       MonsterType
    var location:   HordeGameData.Location
    var isFaceUp:   Bool            = false
    var soundAppear: String         = "skeletonWalk4.mp3"
    var soundHit:    String         = "skeletonHit1.mp3"
    var soundDefend: String         = "skeletonEmerge1.mp3"
    var soundAttack: String         = "skeletonHit4.mp3"
    var soundDead:   String         = "skeletonShatter1.mp3"
    var playSound:   Bool           = true
    let images:      ImagesCatalog
    var imagePic:    String
    var scaleFactor: CGFloat        = 0.5
    var active:      Bool           = false
    var slash:       Bool           = false
    var description: String         = ""
    var status:      MonsterStatus = .Normal
    
    
    func returnColor() -> Color {
        if isFaceUp && isBoss {
            return .red
        } else {
            return .red
        }
    }
    
    func provideID() -> String {
        return String(self.id)
    }
    
    mutating func playSoundToggle() {
        self.playSound.toggle()
    }
    
    mutating func reduceStrengthBy(_ amount: Int) {
        if strength > amount {
            self.strength -= amount
        }
    }
    
    
    mutating func defineImage(status: MonsterStatus, slash: Bool) {
        self.status = status
        switch status {
        case .Normal: imagePic = images.Normal
            if playSound {
                Sound.play(file: self.soundAppear)
            }
        case .Attack: imagePic = images.Attack
            if playSound {
                Sound.play(file: self.soundAttack)
            }
        case .Defend: imagePic = images.Defend
            if playSound {
                Sound.play(file: self.soundDefend)
            }
        case .Hit   : imagePic = images.Hit
            if playSound {
                Sound.play(file: self.soundHit)
            }
        case .Dead  : imagePic = images.Dead
            if playSound {
                Sound.play(file: self.soundDead)
            }
        }
        
        self.slash = slash
    }
    
    mutating func nextImage() {
        switch self.status {
        case .Normal: defineImage(status: .Attack,  slash: false)
        case .Attack: defineImage(status: .Defend,  slash: false)
        case .Defend: defineImage(status: .Hit,     slash: false)
        case .Hit   : defineImage(status: .Dead,    slash: false)
        case .Dead  : defineImage(status: .Normal,  slash: false)
        }
    }
    
    mutating func setID(_ id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
    
    mutating func reduceLife() {
        life -= 1
    }
    
    mutating func addLife() {
        life += 1
    }
    
    
    func provideLife() -> String {
        
        var lifeString = ""
        for _ in 0..<life {
            lifeString.append("")
        }
        return lifeString
    }


    ///
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     
        case id
        case name
        case imagePrefix
        case strength
        case life
        case fleeChance
        case isBoss
        case flying
        case mage
        case venomous
        case giant
        case carnivore
        case herbivore
        case type
        case location
        case soundAppear
        case soundHit
        case soundDefend
        case soundAttack
        case soundDead
        case images
        case scaleFactor
        case description
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id          = try container.decode(Int.self,        forKey: .id)
        name        = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .name)
        imagePrefix = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .imagePrefix)
        strength    = try container.decode(Int.self,        forKey: .strength)
        life        = try container.decode(Int.self,        forKey: .life)
        fleeChance  = try container.decode(Int.self,        forKey: .fleeChance)
        isBoss      = try container.decode(Bool.self,       forKey: .isBoss)
        flying      = try container.decode(Bool.self,       forKey: .flying)
        mage        = try container.decode(Bool.self,       forKey: .mage)
        venomous    = try container.decode(Bool.self,       forKey: .venomous)
        giant       = try container.decode(Bool.self,       forKey: .giant)
        carnivore   = try container.decode(Bool.self,       forKey: .carnivore)
        herbivore   = try container.decode(Bool.self,       forKey: .herbivore)
        
        
        let monsterTypeValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        type = MonsterType(rawValue: monsterTypeValue) ?? .Error
        
        let locationValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .location)
        location = HordeGameData.Location(rawValue: locationValue) ?? .Error
    
        soundAppear        = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .soundAppear)
        soundHit           = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .soundHit)
        soundDefend        = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .soundDefend)
        soundAttack        = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .soundAttack)
        soundDead          = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .soundDead)

        

    images = .init(Normal: imagePrefix + "Normal",
                  Attack: imagePrefix  + "Attack",
                  Defend: imagePrefix  + "Defend",
                  Hit: imagePrefix     + "Hit",
                  Dead: imagePrefix    + "Dead")
        
    imagePic = imagePrefix + "Normal"

    //    let stringScale = try container.decode(CGFloat.self, forKey: .scaleFactor)
    //    print(stringScale)
      // scaleFactor          = stringScale.CGFloatValue() ?? 0.5
        description          = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .description)
        print("Monster \(id): \(name) imported")
    }
}
```

Decode funtion

```
class MonsterInventory {
    static let shared = MonsterInventory()
    
    var staticItems: [Monster] = []
    
    private init() {
       self.parseMonsterJson()
    }
    
    private func parseMonsterJson() {

        
        
        guard let monsterJsonFileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Monsters", withExtension: "json") else {
            fatalError("Unable to find file")
        }
        
        do {
            let content = try Data(contentsOf: monsterJsonFileUrl)
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            staticItems = try jsonDecoder.decode([Monster].self, from: content)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            staticItems = []
        }
    }
    
    func fetchMonsterWithID(_ id: Int) -> Monster {
        return staticItems.filter{$0.id == id}.first ?? staticItems.filter{$0.id == 10}.first!
    }
    
    
    func fetchMonsterWithName(_ name: String) -> Monster {
        return staticItems.filter{$0.name == name}.first ?? staticItems.filter{$0.id == 10}.first!
    }
    
    
}
```

here is an excerpt of the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Skeleton Warrior",
    "strength": 6,
    "life": 1,
    "fleeChance": 0,
    "isBoss": false,
    "flying": false,
    "mage": false,
    "venomous": false,
    "giant": false,
    "carnivore": false,
    "herbivore": false,
    "type": "Undead",
    "location": "Plains",
    "soundAppear": "skeletonWalk4.mp4",
    "soundHit": "skeletonHit1.mp3",
    "soundDefend": "swordSwoosh2.m4a",
    "soundAttack": "swordSwoosh1.m4a",
    "soundDead": "skeletonShatter2.mp3",
    "imagePrefix": "SkeletonWarrior",
    "imageNormal": "SkeletonWarriorNormal",
    "imageAttack": "SkeletonWarriorAttack",
    "imageDefend": "SkeletonWarriorDefend",
    "imageHit": "SkeletonWarriorHit",
    "imageDead": "SkeletonWarriorDead",
    "scaleFactor": 1.1,
    "description": "A weak skeleton fighter."
  },
...
]
```

Comment: That code would either crash or return a cgfloat it should never return nil. Please could you include the rest of your code without changes so that we can see the full custom decode function.  Thanks

Comment: Also, that isn’t valid JSON so it would be good to see the actual JSON being used if possible. Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister it is a valid JSON following RFC8259 it just contains a extra trailing comma which in no way affects the Decoding in Swift

Comment: @Fogmeister: you are right, it crashed but the error stated that it found nil. But if I add the line to import the CGFloat it cannot import any of the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why are you decoding key by key... I think you should create a `struct` unless you really need to decode key by key (like
flanker mentioned in a comment to this answer).

If you do need to go key by key you need to provide more details on how are you decoding the JSON

This is the struct that fits your JSON

```swift
struct Elm: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var string: String
    var int: Int
    var cgfloat: CGFloat // also can be Double and Float
}
```

You can also change the variables names to follow the camelCase naming.

```swift
struct Elm: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var string: String
    var int: Int
    var cgFloat: Double

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id, string, int, cgFloat = "cgfloat"
    }
}
```

This is how you can decode the object.

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let obj = try! decoder.decode([Elm].self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

In this case the root of your JSON is an array so for that case instead of using `Elm.self` we use `[Elm].self` to decode to the array

This way Swift maps the JSON Key to the matching variable name (or using the Coding Keys like I demonstrated in the second struct)

This was tested in Playgrounds

**UPDATE 1**

Based on your updated question I now see why the individual decodings, but assuming that the key that you are having problems with is the `scaleFactor` which is the only Float number in the sample the code you provided works with no issues at all.

```swift
 // [...]

    // uncommented your code
    scaleFactor = try container.decode(CGFloat.self, forKey: .scaleFactor) 
    let _scaleFactor = try container.decode(CGFloat.self, forKey: .scaleFactor) // both work
      
        description          = try container.decode(String.self,     forKey: .description)
        print("Monster \(id): \(name) imported")
```

[image: playground]

Now you can double check if the reading of the file is being done correctly (if you can read the rest of the file it probably is)

Comment: This is a valid and simple way to decode the (corrected) JSON, but IMO saying its the "proper" way is a bit strong.  There are several reason why you may want to decode key by key in a custom `init(from decoder)`.  Part of the problem here is the ambiguity in the question!

Comment: Fair point @flanker only the original poster can tell us that and that's why started with "I'm unsure why are you decoding key by key" but yes saying it's the proper way it's strong and I will remove I from my answer

Comment: yes thanks, I am using a struct where all my variables are stored. I am modifying some of the entries and have only part of the information in the JSON file, the rest is provided by the app.

Comment: I used the code you provided and it compiles and decodes correctly the value `scaleFactor` assuming that's the one you are having problems with. I'm gonna update my answer but really I don't find a issue unless the problem is with other JSON entry

Comment: Thanks for checking. I just checked the database and one entry of the scaleFactor was empty, therefore converted to a string and could not be imported. I guess I will need to make an error proofing to set the value to 1 if there is anything else than a Double or Float. Silly me. Sorry for bothering you with this. Good input though!

Comment: @NathanaelTse no problem, it happens to everyone ;) Just a hint though, next time past the exact error that the IDE is giving you, I had my share of nulls being found where they shouldn't be on JSONs I probably would have gotten the answer faster. Anyway, happy to help